# Call new thread each time within large loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have 20,000 to 30,000 users, who should receive a message at a given time. `SendMessage` is a service that does API call against a third party site. I have this loop:

```
@users.each do |user|
  ...
  SendMessage.new(user.id)
  ...
end
```

Since there are quite large number of users, the API response takes about one second, and the last user receives the message too later than the scheduled time.

I thought of using `Thread` like this:

```
@users.each do |user|
  ...
  Thread.new{ SendMessage.new(user.id) }
  ...
end
```

Can I do as above? Is it a good idea to use `Thread.new` 20,000 times within a loop? Are there any drawbacks? Is there something else I am supposed to do?

Comment: Does it have to be synchronous?

Comment: no, it can be async

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your need to send 20,000 API calls to a third party provider, and assuming this can be taken async, you should implement this with [`Sidekiq`](https://sidekiq.org) or [`Resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque).

You can issue a request initially, and then poll continuously for status update if needed.

Comment: I am using `Sidekiq`, but there is already similar background job running to generate reports. this has let enqueing of too many jobs and sidekiq stops. :/ . So i wanted to avoid that.

Comment: If you're doing too much async operations and if `Sidekiq` doesn't help, either scale out with `Sidekiq` or add `RabbitMQ` to your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet. But if my answer it's not usefull I will destroy it.
So, if you use `each`, all records will be loaded into memory, it's not good idea when you have more 20 000 records.
Try to use [find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each). The find is performed by find_in_batches with a batch size of 1000  (or as specified by the :batch_size option).

Comment: Thank you,  I will consider this.